# C array of structs giving strange behaviour

Tags: c, object, memory-management

I am new to programming in C so I have started making a simple project. I am having an issue with the below code, which seems to be something related to the way memory is managed in C but I'm not sure.
I have a 1280x720 array of Particles which I fill with zeros and with "none". Then I fill in a single entry at (1,1). Finally I print out all the 'particles' that are not "none". The strange behaviour comes from the fact that when I do this I get an output of:
`721 0 sand 1 1 sand`
Clearly the second value should be there, but the first should not. I have tried with different values of x,y and it always adds 720 to x, and subtracts 1 from y.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char name[10];
  int colour;
} Particle;

Particle particles[1280][720];

void main() {
  //Fill in the 1280 x 720 array with 0's and None
  for (int y=0; y<720; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<1280; x++) {
      particles[y][x].colour = 0x000000;
      strcpy(particles[y][x].name, "none");
    }
  }

  //Copy in 1 pixel of sand
  strcpy(particles[1][1].name, "sand");
  particles[1][1].colour = 0xFFFF00;

  //Print out all the pixels that are not none, which should
  //just print out a single pixel at (1,1)
  for (int y=0; y<720; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<1280; x++) {
      if (strcmp("none",particles[y][x].name) != 0) {
        printf("%d %d %s\n",x,y,particles[y][x].name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry if this is a simple question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each rows of the array `particles` have only 720 elements, so `particles[y][x]` is out-of-range when `x >= 720`. Accessing out-of-range element invokes *undefined behavior*.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) J.2 Undefined behavior:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
> given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int
> a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

Allocate enough elements to avoid buffer overrun. It seems you should use

```
Particle particles[720][1280];
```

instead of

```
Particle particles[1280][720];
```

It is better to define the width and height as macro to avoid typo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720

typedef struct {
  char name[10];
  int colour;
} Particle;

Particle particles[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

void main() {
  //Fill in the WIDTH x HEIGHT array with 0's and None
  for (int y=0; y<HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<WIDTH; x++) {
      particles[y][x].colour = 0x000000;
      strcpy(particles[y][x].name, "none");
    }
  }

  //Copy in 1 pixel of sand
  strcpy(particles[1][1].name, "sand");
  particles[1][1].colour = 0xFFFF00;

  //Print out all the pixels that are not none, which should
  //just print out a single pixel at (1,1)
  for (int y=0; y<HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<WIDTH; x++) {
      if (strcmp("none",particles[y][x].name) != 0) {
        printf("%d %d %s\n",x,y,particles[y][x].name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```